# Creating console application in Java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, console-application

How do I go about creating a simple console application (like one that prints hello world to console) using VS Code in Java? How do I get VS Code to generate proper setup files for project?

Comment: [Read this?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good tutorial on Visual Studio Code page that you can find [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) teaching you to use that for Java Development.

I've put some references [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1QXBWjX9oMz9hGn0SaVDaSHrn8S3HYCL9mEeLdrDUvWE/edit#slide=id.g880f3efa41_1_2) as well!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file like Name.java

Then write your Class. You can run it with 'F5'

Comment: This does not work for me. There is no run option when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Java is installed?

And do you have installed java extensions for vsCode?
Here's the link:

code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/extensions

Comment: Java is already installed, but when I create a single java file and try to run it from terminal/run active file in vs code, it does not work. Can you post screenshots running it through?